# adding a complex component onclick results in Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a complex component via a button to my dom:

```
const BlockChain = () => {
  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([Block, Block] as typeof Block[]);

  return (
    <Layout activeRoute="blockChain">
      {blocks.map((b, i) => b({ blockNr: i, leadingZeros: 3, speed: 7 }))}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const _blocks = blocks.slice(0);
          _blocks.push(Block);
          setBlocks(_blocks);
        }}
      >
        add Block
      </button>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

and predictably I get an Error: `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`
is there a way to add the Component like this?

My Block component uses set interval and a bunch of useRef and useState hooks

Comment: You can't store components in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The state can be any type. Each piece of state holds a single value, which can be an object, an array, a boolean, or any other type you can imagine.**

A component is a function, you cannot store a function inside state.

In your case, you should store an array of objects with your blocks data, and pass it to your .map function. Inside your map you will then return your  component passing the data through props.

Comment: I feared thats what I have to do

Comment: Don't fear, once you practice, it becomes natural :)